# Subsetting Dates and Times Across Multiple Data Frames in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, subset

I'm new to R, so this may very well be a simple problem, but it's causing me a lot of difficulty.

I am trying to subset between two values found across data frames, and I am having difficulty when trying to subset between these two values. I will first describe what I've done, what is working, and then what is not working.

I have two data frames. One has a series of storm data, including dates of storm events, and the other has a series of data corresponding to discharge for many thousands of monitoring events. I am trying to see if any of the discharge data corresponds within the storm event start and end dates/times.

What I have done thus far is as follows:

Example discharge data:

```
    X.  DateTime        Depth   DateTime1           newcol
1   3   8/2/2013 13:15  0.038   2013-08-02 13:15:00 1375463700
2   4   8/2/2013 13:30  0.038   2013-08-02 13:30:00 1375464600
3   5   8/2/2013 13:45  0.039   2013-08-02 13:45:00 1375465500
4   6   8/2/2013 14:00  0.039   2013-08-02 14:00:00 1375466400
```

Example storm data:

```
    Storm newStart  newEnd
1   1   1382125500  1382130000
2   2   1385768100  1385794200

#Make a value to which the csv files are attached
CA_Storms <- read.csv(file = "CA_Storms.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
CA_adj <- read.csv(file = "CA_Adj.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#strptime function (do this for all data sets)
CA_adj$DateTime1 <- strptime(CA_adj$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
CA_Storms$Start.time1 <- strptime(CA_Storms$Start.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
CA_Storms$End.time1 <- strptime(CA_Storms$End.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

#Make dates and times continuous
CA_adj$newcol <- as.numeric(CA_adj$DateTime1)
CA_Storms$newStart <- as.numeric(CA_Storms$Start.time1)
CA_Storms$newEnd <- as.numeric(CA_Storms$End.time1)
```

This allows me to do the following subsets successfully:

```
    CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol == "1375463700", ]

Example output:   
 X.       DateTime Depth           DateTime1     newcol
    1  3 8/2/2013 13:15 0.038 2013-08-02 13:15:00 1375463700

CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol == CA_Storms[1,19], ]

 X.       DateTime         Depth  DateTime1           newcol
7403 7408 10/18/2013 15:45 0.058 2013-10-18 15:45:00 1382125500

CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol <= CA_Storms[1,20], ]
```

However, whenever I try to have it move between two values, such as in:

`CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol >= CA_Storms[1,19] & CA_adj$newol <= CA_Storms[1,20], ]`

it responds with this:

```
[1] X.        DateTime  Depth     DateTime1 newcol   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I know this output is incorrect, as, through a cursory look through my large data set, there is at least one value that falls within these criteria.

What gives?

Comment: Please post a sample data and desired output.

Comment: Is not `CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol >= CA_Storms[1,19] | CA_adj$newol <= CA_Storms[1,20], ]` what you want?

Comment: @Soheil thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the post so these are now added.

Comment: @Robert I have tried that, and it yields that same results. Also, I think I want it to be &, yes, since I am looking for which discharge periods exist at a date/time that is between those two values and not excluded from them?

Comment: `CA_adj[CA_adj$newcol == CA_Storms[1,19], ]` What do you get with this? row 1 and column 19?

Comment: @Soheil I get the following output:

 X.               DateTime            Depth  DateTime1                 newcol
7403 7408 10/18/2013 15:45 0.058 2013-10-18 15:45:00 1382125500

Edit: I have put the output in the main text, since it isn't showing up in the appropriate format in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
discharge<-data.frame( x=c(3,4,5,6),
                       DateTime=c("8/2/2013 13:15","8/2/2013 13:30",
                                  "8/2/2013 13:45","8/2/2013 14:00"),
                       Depth=c(0.038, 0.038, 0.039, 0.039)
                     ) 
 discharge$DateTime1<- as.POSIXct(discharge$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

storm<-data.frame( storm=c(1,2),
                   start=c("8/2/2013 13:15","8/2/2013 16:30"),
                   end=c("8/2/2013 13:45","8/2/2013 16:45")
                 )

 storm$start<- as.POSIXct(storm$start, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
 storm$end<- as.POSIXct(storm$end, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")


discharge[(discharge$DateTime1>=storm[1,2] & discharge$DateTime1<=storm[1,3]),]
```